# Why joinColumns is undefined when trying to make a relation?

Tags: typescript, typeorm, nestjs

I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'joinColumns' of undefined
    at <...>/src/persistence/SubjectOperationExecutor.ts:282:47` error when trying to create new object of entity with a relation. Why is this happening?

In one entity I have:

```
@Entity('users')
export class User extends WhateverEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @ManyToMany(type => Account, account => account.users, {
    cascadeInsert: true,
    cascadeUpdate: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  accounts: Account[]
}
```

The second one:

```
@OneToOne(type => User, user => user.id)
owner: User

@ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.accounts)
users: User[]
```

And I save like this (where `owner: User` and `users: User[]`:

```
const account = new Account()
account.owner = owner
account.users = users || []

return this.accountRepository.save(account)
```

It doesn't work even if I comment out `account.owner = owner` or `account.users = users || []`. It saves account, but doesn't make the relation.

---

Additional info: if I `console.log` the `account` right before saving - it does have owner and users inside as instances of `User` class.

---

`owner` and `users` are User-entity objects that are already in database.

Answer (score 18):

You may forgot to put `@JoinColumn()` decorator on to your `@OneToOne` relation.
It must be like there

```
@OneToOne(type => User, user => user.id)
@JoinColumn()
owner: User
```